# Grails Configuration - proper way to dynamically determine configuration property

Tags: grails

I'm trying to access a Grails property that I've created using dynamic logic to determine which property file to use.

This is the simplified example:

String pathToKey = "Level1.Level2.Level3"

assert config.rootProperties[pathToKey].key ## Returns empty key value
assert config.rootProperties.Level1.Level2.Level3.key ## Returns proper key value

What is the proper way to create a multie level/object configuration file and dynamically access the key?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution I was looking for:

```
String pathAndKey = "rootProperties.Level1.Level2.Level3.key"

String value = config.flatten().getProperty(pathAndKey)
```